# Why does my twitter Application access-level is Read-only? and how can I change that?

Tags: php, twitter

At the bottom of the details page There's the (Your access token) Section, the access level there is read only.

I'm trying to make an application that makes me follow all the users who log in to my site using twitter, I'm successfully making the users follow me, but I'm not able to follow the users, any idea why is that, and how can I change the access level of my own twitter account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to dev.twitter.com/apps
2. Select your app
3. Go to the Settings tab
4. Look for 'Application Type'
5. Change it to Read and Write

### Update

You also need to update your access token:

1. Go to your apps details page
2. Click the recreate your access token button

Comment: I've already done this, and the application access level is read/write however my own access is Read-only.

Comment: You also need to update your access token, sorry, I forgot that. I've added an explanation to my post

Comment: @Jeroen Please update; `Application Type` does not exist in settings any longer.

Comment: @Jeroen Sure. I'll do that when I get the chance ;)

Answer (score 10):

The "Application Type" section is no longer present in the Twitter Developers portal. To change the permissions of your application follow these steps:

1. Go dev.twitter.com/apps.
2. Select your application.
3. Go to the "Settings" tab.
4. Go to the "User authentication settings" section at the bottom.
5. Add the authentication. While adding, make sure to **choose OAuth 1.0a**. Without choosing this option all your access tokens will be `Read-only`.
6. Upon selecting "OAuth 10.a", a new form section will appear called "OAUTH 1.0A SETTINGS". In this section choose the permissions you wish to have in the "App permissions" field.
7. Fill in the rest of the fields (Callback URL, Website URL, etc.). You may fill in gibberish if you're not planning on implementing a user-facing OAuth flow (e.g. need that token for internal automation instead).
8. Submit the form.
9. Go to the "Keys and Tokens" tab on your application detail page.
10. Locate the "Authentication Tokens" section, in it the "Access Token and Secret" group.
11. **Click "Add"/"Regenerate"**. This will generate a new token with *write* permissions.

Your access token will now have the permissions that you've specified in the "OAUTH 1.0A SETTINGS" field.

Comment: hi, tx, how do you fill up CallBack URL, Website URL (7th step)?

Comment: @JeJe I simply skipped that (or entered gibberish). If you're not planning on implementing an actual user-driven OAuth flow, you don't need those.

Comment: This is the way. incredible that it's this ridiculous!